# Display countdown timer with bar on screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to want to create a countdown timer with a progress bar (a backwards progress bar).

I want it to tell me when it reached the end of the time and I want to be able to stop and restart it whenever I want.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Matt Legend Gemmel has a [great video](https://vimeo.com/17158932) on how to approach Custom UI Controls.